# Passing Queries from Postgres to JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, distinct

I'm newbie

I'm trying pass this Postgres query to JPA/JPQL

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(srv.code) AS Serv_Cod,
    srv.id AS Serv_id,
    srv.description AS Serv_Desc
FROM db.Category AS cat
    join db.Classification AS cla ON cat.id = cla.cat_id
    join db.Service AS srv ON srv.id = cla.srv_id
WHERE cat.id = 10
ORDER BY srv.id;
```

Now I want to write the same Query, I have the Entities with the same name Table.

Classification

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Classification", schema = "db")
@Audited
public class Classification implements Identifiable<Long> {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "srv_id", nullable = true)
    private Service service;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cat_id", nullable = true)
    private Category category;

    ....

}
```

Service

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Service", schema = "db")
@Audited
public class Service implements Identifiable<Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "code", nullable = false)
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    private String description;

    ....

}
```

I was reading, but I'm very confused...

I don't know how to write the `ON` for the `JOIN`, and establish the DISTINCT for a Column/Field.

```
Long myID = 25L;
this.em.createQuery("SELECT NEW SomeDto(srv.id, srv.code, srv.description)" 
        + " FROM Classification cla"
                    + "JOIN cla·cat_id cat"
                    + "JOIN cla·srv_id srv"
                    + "WHERE cat.id = :id"
        ,BaseObjectDto.class).setParameter("id", myID).getResultList();
```

Thank you for you valuable Help.

Comment: Can you show the entities Category and Classification how they are mapped?

Comment: already @SimonMartinelli thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is very simple. When you have ToOne relationships you can navigate to the related entity. There is no need to JOIN ON.

Even with ToMany there is no need for the ON because this is already defined in the mapping.

So the query will look like:

```
SELECT NEW SomeDto(cla.service.id, cla.service.code, cla.service.description)
FROM Classification cla
WHERE category.id = :id
```

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT NEW SomeDto(cla.service.id, cla.service.code, cla.service.description) FROM Classification cla WHERE cla.category.id = :id ORDER BY cla.service.id`   Thank you!!